# Certificate from Goddady

Tags: certificate, pem, pfx, p12, spc

I created a certificate through GoDaddy. I need to create a pfx or p12 certificate in order to sign it in a windows executable. I followed GoDaddy's instructions from [this link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698), but I was unable to generate the pfx file. I have .spc and .pem files and I want to generate a pfx file. could you help me?

Comment: My general advice is to _not_ use GoDaddy for anything other than a very basic website, e.g. for a small business or personal site.  I also couldn't get very far with them, their support was almost non existent, and I winded up going with DigiCert (full support).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm using a GoDaddy's certificate and want to know if there is a way to create a pfx file?